# How do I prevent AEM stripping out the href from a RTE that has a default value which contains a link?

Tags: aem, rte

I have a default value set for a RTE filed in AEM.  This value is shown correct when the dialog is first open however when it is saved and reopened the href has been stripped from the A tag.  (This is an external link)

It works correct if this href is then re-added using the RTE link button but naturally I want this to work correctly first time.

I am new to AEM and currently have the following (note: for this example I have changed the URL and copy to test versions):

```
<branchResultsCopy
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    externalStyleSheets="[/etc/designs/rtg/clientlibs/author/style/source/rte.css]"
    fieldLabel="Branch results copy"
    name="./branchresultscopy"
    defaultValue="&lt;p&gt;If you'd like information about blah blah blah, visit our &lt;a target='_blank' link-checker='skip' href='https://www.testurl.com'&gt;Link text&lt;/a&gt; page.&lt;/p&gt;"
    xtype="richtext">
        <htmlRules
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <links
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    protocols="[http://,https://]"/>
        </htmlRules>
        <rtePlugins
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <edit
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                        <htmlPasteRules
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                                <allowBasics
                                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                    anchor="{Boolean}true"
                                     bold="{Boolean}true"
                                />
                        </htmlPasteRules>
                </edit>
                <format
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    features="[bold,italic]"/>
                <lists
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    features="[ordered,unordered]"/>
                <links
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    features="*"/>
        </rtePlugins>
</branchResultsCopy>
```

Comment: Is the link you are using valid (I assume the example is a dummy url)? Maybe even with the link-checker='skip' (never heard of this) the link gets stripped by the link checker.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I checked and the URL in my real code is going to a valid link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main problem is the syntax used in the defaultValue field.
I just did the test myself by adding a link to a text component, then through CRXDE I went and took the ./text of the jcr:content and copypasted that directly to the defaultValue field of the component.

Then I added a new instance of the component to a page, edited it, the default value was in the RTE, I simply clicked saved and the link stayed intact.

I did a package of the component to check what AEM put in the XML, and it was rather odd to say the least, all the > chars are left intact, while all the < are escaped.

here's my defaultValue that was in the package's dialog.xml:

```
defaultValue="&lt;p>Timeless beauty. Classic simplicity. It must be the circle! Each &lt;a href=&quot;http://google.ca&quot;>Geometrixx-brand&lt;/a> circle is handcrafted from an infinite number of very skinny isoceles triangles arrange in, well, a circle! We guarantee that our circles are not simply&lt;i> n&lt;/i>-gons, where &lt;i>n&lt;/i> is a very large number; ours are guaranteed round, no matter how closely you look. test&lt;/p>&#xa;"
```

Notice that they use &quot for the attributes.

Also, a small warning, the RTEPlugin does not like the link-checker="skip" attribute, it's going to strip it out.

You need to tell it that you have a custom attribute to handle if you want it to keep the link-checker.

The only way I know how to do this is through the classic dialog though
This requires to add a new node to the linkAttributes in the linkDialogConfig of the RTEPlugin.

something like this

```
<skipchecker
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    attribute="link-checker"
    fieldDescription="Skip link checker"
    fieldLabel="Skip Checker"
    name="./linkdialog/skip"
    xtype="selection">   
        <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <noskip
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="No Skip"
                value=""/>  
            <skip
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                text="Skip"
                value="skip"/>         
        </options>
</skipchecker>
```

All this was testing with the non-sightly component though, you didn't mention which version of the text component you were using.  The Sightly component may be working a bit differently though but the classic dialog is the same and should be using the same plugin.

Comment: Thanks Francois, the &quot; bit solved my main issue.